# My Enviroment Background doesn't show up?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I'm trying to do a Space scene on Cycles so i'm using a Star map background as an Enviroment Map, i made the Nodes already, the texture/image shows up on the Preview..but not in the Render, why? It's the last step i need for this render but this is still giving me troubles :/

[image]

Comment: What is the mix for?

Comment: You could try swapping 'Background' shader and 'Mix shader'

Comment: The Mix was for visibility, i based my nodes on another scene.
I just swapped the Background and Mix Shader, but nothing happens.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend?

Comment: Ok, i uploaded it here, the image file is the actual background.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/dvnlu1rz8ulbxw7/SolarSystemBG.rar

Comment: Shows up fine on my machine. You need to uncheck "Transparent" under "Film" on the "Render" tab  of your "Properties Panel".

Comment: Hmm, but without modifying anything in the nodes?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't open the .rar file.  Could you try [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead please?

Comment: Wait, the solution of @galingong worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment is not showing up in the render because you have Transparent checked in the Film section of the Render property panel. Uncheck that and it will work.

I would also add that if you DO want to composite the foreground and background element, to leave the Transparent box checked. Then you can enable the Environment render pass and combine the foreground and background renders in the compositor.

Comment: If someone answers a question correctly in the comments we usually give them a day or so to put it as an answer so they can get the rep, see [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/436/5705).

Comment: If he wants to post his solution as an official answer, that's fine by me.